Как запаковать большой файл в .tar?
Существует ли вообще реализация записи в .tar большого файла, в которой можно было бы указать свой буфер? Это нужно среди прочего чтобы контролировать прогресс запаковки.
Код для примера:
byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024 * 1024);
string item = @"R:\Bigfile.dat";
using (FileStream _writestream = File.Create(@"R:\test.tar")
using (TarWriter tarwriter = new(_writestream, TarEntryFormat.Pax, leaveOpen: false))
using (FileStream srcFile = new(item, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string fileName = item.Remove(0, mainDir.Length + 1).Replace('\\', '/');
    PaxTarEntry te = new(TarEntryType.RegularFile, fileName)
    {
        DataStream = new MemoryStream()
    };
    
    int currentBlockSize = 0;
    while ((currentBlockSize = srcFile.Read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        te.DataStream.Write(buffer.AsSpan(0, currentBlockSize));
    }
    te.DataStream.Position = 0;
    tarwriter.WriteEntry(te);
}
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);

Если его использовать - будет большое использование оперативной памяти. Да, вероятно потому что запись будет вестись в MemoryStream(). Но какие есть более правильные варианты, если нужно записать ОЧЕНЬ большой файл? Чтобы запись сразу велась в .tar-файл, а не в оперативку, и я мог контролировать объём каждой итерации цикла записи через размер буфера.

Зачем у тебя там используется Memory stream?

@evo потому что там нужно что-то использовать. Если заранее не присвоить DataStream какой-то поток, то невозможно будет заполнять DataStream в цикле, который идёт дальше по коду.

Нет, я не об этом, вы копируете открытый поток файла в память, и из памяти его архивируете, зачем? Передайте туда ссылку на поток файла открытого.

И уточните что имеется ввиду под контролем записи, так ничего не понятно, если что то всегда можно FileStream перегрузить.

@evo да, действительно, мне уже подсказали что можно просто сделать DataStream = srcFile, и это не приведёт к чрезмерному использованию оперативки. Но если честно, помимо прочего я бы хотел иметь возможность контролировать прогресс запаковки файла в .tar... Ну то есть чтобы программа могла в процентах отображать ход запаковки. А если сделать просто DataStream = srcFile (удалив дальнейший цикл while), то запаковка будет не подконтрольна мне, я не смогу отображать проценты...

Ну, сделайте наследника класса от FileStream, и управляйте чтением оттуда, ведь то что вы тут копируете никак не относится к упаковке данных. Либо перегружайте класс TarWriter, либо FileStream, тут как душа лежит.

Этот код не рабочий, потому что он занимается только копированием данных в MS. Архивация в этот момент даже не начинается, как я понимаю. Архивация начинается вот здесь tarwriter.WriteEntry(te). Уточните, что значит контрлировать, какого именно контроля вам не хватает?

@aepot речь про контроль над прогрессом запаковки в .tar. Хотелось бы иметь возможность знать о проценте прогресса. Я не понимаю как его фиксировать в данном случае. Выше evo рекомендует сделать свой вариант FileStream, но эта опция выглядит не шибко удобной и малость сложной для меня. Неужели нет более "штатного" варианта контролировать прогресс запаковки?

Контроль это пуск/пауза/отмена и т.д. Отображение информации о прогрессе это отображение информации. Как можете догадаться, реализация этих штук совершенно разная может быть. Конкретизируйте вопрос. Если отображение прогресса, то так и напишите. А пока непонятно, зачем вам буферы и т.д.

@aepot обычно подсчёт прогресса делается через контроль того, сколько байт в каждый момент времени записалось в файл. А чтобы это сделать, обычно используется буфер, куда заносятся данные которые нужно записать. Подсчёт прогресса можно сделать через свой вариант FileStream или свой TarWriter, но мне хотелось бы иметь вариант проще.

Вы не в том направлении думаете. У вас нет никакой записи в файл здесь, у вас есть чтение. Вы открываете файл и отдаете поток архиватору. Можно вокруг файла обернуть своим потоком и отдавать свой прокси-поток, который и будет оповещать о прогрессе. Ничего писать никуда не нужно. Вот здесь я решал схожую задачу, но ваша проще.

@aepot, да, я знаю такой вариант, просто надеялся что можно как-то обойтись без подобного...

Не получится обойтись. И страшного в наследовании ничего нет.
